# How would I be able to add an Embed Pagination using Discord's Buttons? (Discord.JS V16)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been trying to figure out how to make a 2 page embed using Discord's integrated buttons, but a lot of my attempts ended up in an error when restarting the bot, or nothing happening at all. I left the last thing I tried at the top which was from the discord.js guide. (Note: I am not using slash commands)

I am fairly new to Discord.JS so I tried to follow multiple tutorials and use different packages, but a lot of them ended up being outdated and made before Discord fully released buttons and it ended up not working.

Code:

```js
const { ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'mods',
    aliases: ['m'],
    description: 'This will showcase the current mods',
    execute(message, _args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData){

        const next = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('next')
            .setLabel('Next')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

        const back = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('back')
            .setLabel('Back')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);


        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#f1cbff')
        .setTitle('Showcasing current mods for The Final Destination')
        .setAuthor({name: 'The Grinner', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({text: 'Provided by The Grinner!', iconURL: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a2374bd6-8b00-47d8-9c2d-a6dc4973be58/dea55tw-f3b08cec-71b4-47ec-bbc0-4ea56a95a94f.png/v1/fill/w_627,h_713,strp/jerma985_accurate_height_morph_by_rosiepasta_dea55tw-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NzEzIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYTIzNzRiZDYtOGIwMC00N2Q4LTljMmQtYTZkYzQ5NzNiZTU4XC9kZWE1NXR3LWYzYjA4Y2VjLTcxYjQtNDdlYy1iYmMwLTRlYTU2YTk1YTk0Zi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjI3In1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.0f4pfe3LnmwMN_RTePIhfqyUD7ek2eZUeKmLPx4oo-w'})
        .setThumbnail('https://thumbs.gfycat.com/RapidCheerfulAnt-max-1mb.gif')
        .addFields(
            {name: "Mr. Crayfish's Furniture Mod", value: 'Adds more furniture (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mrcrayfish-furniture-mod)'},
            {name: "Traveler's Backpack", value: "Adds a bag with shoulder straps that allow it to be carried on one's back. (Literally the definition of backpack)(Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/travelers-backpack)"},
            {name: 'Fresh Animations (Requires Optifine to work, use !modhelp for more information)', value: "Mobs will have better animations, this mod is not needed but is optional (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs/fresh-animations)"},
            {name: 'The Backrooms', value: "It's in the name I don't even have to say anything (Temporarily disabled)"},
            {name: 'MEGA records', value: "Contains the whole arsenal of music discs (.ZIP folder needs to be sent by owner)"},
            {name: 'More MEGA records', value: "Contains a larger arsenal of music discs (.ZIP folder needs to be sent by owner)"},
            {name: 'MORGZ paintings', value: "Adds more paintings (.ZIP folder needs to be sent by owner)"},
            {name: "Farmer's Delight", value: "Adds cooking, new crops and adds a great revamp to farming in general (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/farmers-delight)"},
            {name: 'SecurityCraft', value: "Adds means to reinforce your base and catch any scallywag peeping (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/security-craft)"},
            {name: "Mr. Crayfish's Gun Mod", value: 'Guns will now be permanent. Head down to the GUNS store to buy some! (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mrcrayfishs-gun-mod)'},
            {name: 'Framework', value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/framework)'},
            {name: 'GeckoLib', value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/geckolib)'},
            {name: 'Deeper and Darker', value: 'Adds a whole new dimension as well as new tools, armor, bosses, planks and more (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/deeperdarker)'},
            {name: 'Just Enough Items', value: 'A Quality of Life mod that shows recipes and more info about blocks (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/jei)'},
            {name: 'Ore Excavation', value: 'Mining ore veins and cutting trees will be a lot easier now (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ore-excavation)'},
            {name: 'Watchdog Anti-Cheat', value: "It's in the name I don't have to say anything (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/watchdog-anti-cheat#:~:text=WatchDog%20AntiCheat%20is%20a%20mod,on%20the%20client%20and%20server."},
            {name: 'Serene Seasons', value: 'Seasons will be much better now (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/serene-seasons)'},
            {name: "World Edit", value: "Doesn't add anything but is just better for creating builds (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit)"},
            {name: 'Item Blacklist', value: 'This is just to prevent some idiots from getting loot extremely early (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/item-banning)'},
            {name: 'Security Craft', value: 'Adds better security for the wellbeing of your base! (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/security-craft)'},
            {name: 'Inventory Sorter', value: 'A quality of life mod that sorts chests and your inventory with just a click of a button (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/inventory-sorter)'},
            {name: "Thut's Elevators", value: 'Adds the ability to create fully working elevators (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/thuts-elevators)'},
            {name: "Thut Core", value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/thutcore)'},
            {name: 'LittlePictureFrames', value: 'Allows you to add any paintings you want (Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/littleframes)'},
            {name: 'CreativeCore', value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/creativecore)'},
            //I would like to separate it here with an embed page
            {name: 'CasinoCraft', value: "Adds a wide variety of casino games that can be played at BBC (Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/casinocraft)"},
            {name: 'Lucky77', value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lucky77)'},
            {name: 'Create', value: 'This mod adds an gigantic amount of engineering and new buildings blocks (Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/create)'},
            {name: 'ElytraSlot', value: 'Allows you to have the elytra while simultaneously being able to wear your chestplate (Requested by the worst player in the realm)(Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/elytra-slot)'},
            {name: 'Caelus', value: 'This mod does not add anything but allows other mods to be compatible (Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/caelus)'},
            {name: 'Curios', value: 'Allows you to wear different things without having to take off your chestplate (This is mostly a compatibillity mod)(Link: https://beta.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/curios)'},
        );    

     message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
    }
}
```